# What is a noun that means the target of advocacy?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I'm an advocate, for whom or what do I advocate?  What do we call that thing for which I'm an advocate?

Comment: Do you advocate for a person, a class of people, an animal, a class of animals, an ecosystem, a company, a political entity, a religion, a social concept like equality (or supremacy), or something else?

Comment: I don't think there's a generic word for this. It would probably be something like *advocatee* if it existed.

Comment: I was going to say this question was far too vague, however, I do thing the words "cause" and "position" are sufficiently recipricol at the same time as being sufficiently dependent on the notion of an advocate existing for them to be a useful answer as a "what".  I'm struggling with expressing that logic well enough for an answer.

Comment: For people, some terms that come to mind are "candidate", "petitioner", "defendant", "applicant".... if there were a generic word for "person who is being considered for a point of action" ... I'd say it might be narrow and reciprocal enough.

Comment: @Barmar thank you.  I also believe that this word does not exist.  However, functionally, I may use advocatee because people will know what I'm talking about if I do.

Comment: @NigelJ Whatever the consensus is, I'm fine with.  However, I still believe I've asked a very straight forward question that should continue to be of use.  That's just my opinion.

Comment: @piRSquared Have you read the [tag description](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)? Do you really think your question meets its guidelines for good questions of this type?

Comment: I think you really need to distinguish between an advocate in the sense of a lawyer and someone who supports or promotes a concept.

Comment: @Barmar a lawyer is not an advocate for a person directly, they advocate a -position- or a -cause- pertaining to a person.  A person can have an attorney .. which is a representative, the attorney may or may not advocate positions.

Comment: @Tom22 See definition 2.1 [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/advocate) (maybe it's more of a British usage).

Comment: @Barmar The question is not "what is an advocate" but "what is the target of advocacy".  In that definition,  'puts a case on someone else's behalf' ... is the "x" .  Not just a "case" not just a "client" but "act of putting forward a principle for the benefit of the another" (the client). ?

Comment: @Tom22 What I'm saying is that an advocate for a concept has a cause, while a lawyer type of advocate has a client. I don't think you can encompass them in a single word (would you really say that the client is the lawyer's cause?).

Comment: There is a 'one off'. I may have a "surgeon" but it is not having clients that makes him a surgeon. It is the cutting and sewing. Similarly, what defines an advocate, even the barristers called such, is that they perform a specific type of work among barristers/lawyers - their unique flavor of action, is not advising/drafting contracts, acting as a intermediary, giving advice, but pushing for a certain outcome based active support of their efforts of persuasion. Treating 'Patients' says more than 'clients' to describe surgeons work but words like incisions and operations kind of 'cut closer'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(note: one could argue that more generic answers could work too - a surgeon or a plumber can have clients and I'm sure attorneys using the title Advocate refer to cases and clients in normal parlance... but its fun to find words that can dial in abstract human roles and interactions)

### An advocate has a Cause, a cause has Advocates

While initially believing this question was too broad, I believe the word **cause** is a complete answer, with a nearly reciprocal connection.

> [**cause** from Oxford Online Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cause)
>   noun
>
> 2.
>   a **principle, aim, or movement** **that**, because of a deep commitment, one is prepared to defend or **advocate.**
>
> *"she devoted her life to the cause of deaf people"*

To have a "cause" one must have an "one that will advocate" (well defend is close to advocate)

> [**advocate** from Oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/advocate)
>
> #### **noun**
>
> 1A person or thing that gives rise to an action, phenomenon, or condition.
>
> 1A person who publicly supports or recommends a particular **cause** or policy.
>
> *‘he was an untiring advocate of economic reform’*
>
> 2A person who puts a case on someone else's behalf.
>
> *‘care managers can become advocates for their clients’*
>
> ### **verb**
>
> Publicly recommend or support.
>
> *‘voters supported candidates who advocated an Assembly’*

Now, note the use of the word 'clients'
 ... while they ~can~ become advocates for their clients, the client relationship isn't what makes them an advocate.

( a client relationship is not defined by which services you give them but the formal relationship of agreeing to serve and be served.. in some cases the service may be advocacy other cases health care .. but a person can advocate for another without a client relationship)

What makes them an advocate is **what they do** for their clients

My take, a person who will be helped must have a Cause: a **rise to an action, phenomenon, or condition.**

An advocate argues for a cause or for a person's cause

There is never a 'who' directly, although informally that might be used, really a person serves as an advocate OF something pertaining to the person, not the person themselves but to a state of action related to the person.

.. advocate a persons election, advocate the case of innocence in court, advocate the hiring of an applicants pursuit to be hired.

--

Can you be an advocate without a cause? No I think that there must be a cause .. you're not a client's advocate until they have a cause that you will advocate for.

Can something be a 'cause' (in the sense #2) without an advocate? 
No, I don't think so.
You can have a problem, or a dispute, a religion, or a principle but for those to be called a 'cause' someone must be giving "support or recommendation" 
- support or recommend is step different than understand or believe.

#### An Advocate has a **Cause**

Comment: Well stated.  I like the argument.

Comment: @piRSquared .. I go swept up in the joy of words in thinking about it. (even if my expression wasn't as sweeping)  Wow, "Advocate" is a word that would really lead to a broad trek through what human culture is, values, how people cooperate and govern, through compromise reason and tradition.... ooops.. going off track again