# What do you call a person who is the target of an advocate?

Tags: single-word-requests

At my job, we have set up a serious of groups of people and assigned each of them an advocate, so the group looks a bit like this:

```
Jason
     Mike
     Steve
     Nathan
Dave
     George
     Joe
     Chris
```

These are advocates with the people for whom they advocate below them.  The question is if I'm talking to Dave, and I want to say about George "Well, he's your <insert word here>, so I thought you should know." what word would I use in that space?

I searched through google but couldn't find anything, the closest thing I could find here was this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/425971/what-is-a-noun-that-means-the-target-of-advocacy) , which seems to indicate the word I should use is "cause" but that doesn't seem right to me.  Would this be the proper word to use, or is there a better word or phrase that I could use to convey this meaning?

Comment: In the UK Health-Care sector, the word would be "client". I'm not ruling out that other conditions may require a different word, that's why this isn't being posted as an answer.

Comment: in this specific case the person would be a co-worker, so not exactly a client.  Thank you for helping me narrow it down.

Comment: "Well, he's your **responsibility/team member**, so I thought you should know."

Comment: Are the people who are the subject of the advocacy also members of staff of the organisation or are they, in some sense, clients of the organisation? If they are are members of staff does each advocate represent them as individuals or as a group?

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without knowing much more about the role of these advocates and the nature of their advocacy. Those who are trying to answer the question in its present form are forced to keep making guesses about that.

Comment: "a serious of groups"???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If this was a mental health situation, I'd go with "As x is one of your **charges**, I'd thought you should know...."

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/in-someone-s-charge

"if a person or thing is in your charge, you are responsible for taking care of them"

2. If a business mentoring/oversight division of responsibility, 'protege' may be appropriate.

> What is the difference between mentee and protege? As nouns the
>   difference between mentee and protege
>
> mentee is a person who is being mentored while
>   **protege is a person guided and protected by a more prominent person.**

Mentee vs Protege - What's the difference? | WikiDiff

Answer (score 1):

It is a word rarely used  but it might be helpful in this case.

[defendee](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/defendee)

[1](https://books.google.fr/books?id=OAw_3pErMIgC&q=%22defendee%22&dq=%22defendee%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8uZ7s1N7oAhVuBWMBHe-wDTIQ6AEIaDAG) If you are working alone, stay just in front of and to one side of your defendee.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  "Client".
For example:

It is feared that such a system may affect the confidence in the relations between the client and the defence counsel, who may be perceived as not being independent of the Tribunal.